# dplyr - filling with unique value

Tags: r, dplyr

A pretty basic question, but I wonder in a dataset where the group identifiers define unique values and/or missings, how would you feel the missings with the unique values using `dplyr`? If it is a numeric column I would just do something like:

```
data %>% 
  group_by(groupIDs) %>% 
  mutate(VARwithNA=max(VARwithNA, na.rm=TRUE)
```

but what if it is a character column? Is there a better way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps `mutate(VARwithNA = toString(unique(VARwithNA[!is.na(VARwithNA)])))`

Comment: `mutate(VARwithNA = unique(na.omit(VARwithNA)))` should work with most types of data: numeric, character, date, time, etc.

Comment: thank you for this! I am happy to accept it if you want to write it up as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that `unique` values length may not match the number of rows for each group. Using a reproducible example

```
data(mtcars)
mtcars$carb[c(5, 6, 10, 31)] <- NA
mtcars %>% 
   group_by(am) %>%
   mutate(carb = unique(carb[!is.na(carb)]))
```

> Error: Column `carb` must be length 19 (the group size) or one, not 4

---

In that case, it is better to either paste them as a single string

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
   group_by(groupIDs) %>% 
   mutate(VARwithNA = toString(unique(VARwithNA[!is.na(VARwithNA)])))
```

or keep as a `list` column

```
data %>% 
   group_by(groupIDs) %>% 
   mutate(VARwithNA = list(unique(VARwithNA[!is.na(VARwithNA)])))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `unique` will extract the (only) unique value and *keep its type*. The advantage of the solution below is that it should work for most data types (numeric, character, logical, date, time, etc).

```
data %>% 
  group_by(groupIDs) %>% 
  mutate(VARwithNA=unique(na.omit(VARwithNA)))
```

Note that this will fail with "Replacement has length 0" if there is no available (i.e. non-NA) values.